# Updating to .NET Core 2.0: The type 'Color' exists in both 'Shaman.System.Drawing' and 'System.Drawing.Primitives'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-2.0

I am updating a .net core 1.0 project to .net core 2.0, it works fine in .net core 1.0, I have complied other codes such as `Starup.cs`, `.csproj` and authentication, but after that, errors comes out like these:

```
Error   CS0433  The type 'Color' exists in both 'Shaman.System.Drawing, Version=1.0.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=18bc04d2eb1e1518' and 'System.Drawing.Primitives, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'   ProjectResourceMaster   C:\Projects\Project-Resource-Master\src\MinSetupCore\Controllers\ProjectsController.cs  1326    Active
```

I used type `Color` like 100 times in many controllers, the error occurs at every places where `Color` is used.

The weird thing is I didn't even refer `Shaman.System.Drawing` in my references, how does it even refer to it?

p.s: `Shaman.System.Drawing(1.0.1.2)` is a package within the nuget package named `Shaman.EPPlus(1.0.1.2)`, I use this package for some Excel feature, but I didn't meant to use `Shaman.System.Drawing`

Comment: dotnet core 1.0 and 1.1 did not include the System.Drawing namespace, which is why it compiled fine.  2.0 added this namespace from the standard framework (part of the tripling of API's ported from standard).  This is why you are now getting the conflict.  You want to specify only one or the other in most files, if you need both you'll have to use the fully qualified name each time.

Comment: Thank you Erik, I did tried use fully qualified name(eg. System.Drawing.Color.SlateGrey) in my code, and I commented out "using System.Drawing", but it gives me the same error.

Comment: Currently your only hope is to ping Shaman guys and see if they have an updated version that works well with .NET Core 2.0, which they should. They made a mistake by assuming .NET Core would never have `System.Drawing`, and they are the ones who should fix that mistake.

Comment: This is telling you exactly where you used the different type: `ProjectsController` line 1326

You can then qualify the namespace of the type.